# Difference in DATEPART MILLISECONDS from COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL 120 to 130

Tags: sql-server-2016

I've got a SQL Server 2016 database running in compatibility level 120. When I run the following query:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE testdb SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120

DECLARE @d VARCHAR(30) = '2019-11-05 07:31:47.677'
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = @d
SELECT @d as [@d], @dt as [@dt], DATEPART(MILLISECOND, @d) as [@ms_d], DATEPART(MILLISECOND, @dt) as [@ms_dt]
```

I get the expected result:

```
@d                             @dt                     @ms_d       @ms_dt
------------------------------ ----------------------- ----------- -----------
2019-11-05 07:31:47.677        2019-11-05 07:31:47.677 677         677
```

However, when I change the compatibility level to 130, I get:

```
@d                             @dt                     @ms_d       @ms_dt
------------------------------ ----------------------- ----------- -----------
2019-11-05 07:31:47.677        2019-11-05 07:31:47.677 677         676
```

Any thoughts as to why I'm getting **676** under compatibility level 130?

I've reviewed the [Changes in compatibility level 130](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4010261/sql-server-and-azure-sql-database-improvements-in-handling-data-types), and see the rounding changes involving datetime conversions, but nothing appears to me to explain this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As of SQL Server **2008**, you should *stop using* `DATETIME` and use the much more precise `DATETIME2(n)` datatype instead.

Comment: Hi @marc_s, that DATETIME is deprecated is clear from the docs. Converting hundreds of DATETIME columns to DATETIME2 in large legacy databases is easier said than done.